# Foreach multiple variables

Tags: php, foreach

I use the PHP variable $sku to remove certain products from the export. The code below works good if I only want to remove the product with SKU X from the export.

`foreach ($skus as $key => $sku){if ($sku == "X") return "";`

But if I want to remove products with SKU X and/or Y and/or Z from the export, the code below gives empty output. Any idea what is the issue here?

`foreach ($skus as $key => $sku){if ($sku == "X" || $sku == "Y" || $sku == "Z") return "";`

Update: I have changed the function, but now I am getting Fatal error: 'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in your code on line 32 (continue;).

```
function get_order_item_lines($skus = '', $qty = ''){
    
    $xml = '';
    if (!empty($skus) && is_array($skus)){
        
        foreach ($skus as $key => $sku){
            if (strpos(strtoupper($sku, "Z")) === 0) return "";
            $xml .= "<L>".PHP_EOL;
            $xml .= "<P>" . $sku . "</P>".PHP_EOL;
            $xml .= "<Q>" . (empty($qty[$key]) ? "" : $qty[$key]) . "</Q>".PHP_EOL;
            $xml .= "</L>".PHP_EOL;
        }

    } else {
        $skus = explode( ",", $skus );
        if ( !empty( $skus[0] ) && !empty( $qty[0] ) ) {
            if (strpos(strtoupper($skus[0], "Z")) === 0) return "";
            $xml .= "<L>".PHP_EOL;
            $xml .= "<P>" . trim( $skus[0] ) . "</P>".PHP_EOL;
            $xml .= "<Q>" . (empty($qty[0]) ? "" : $qty[0]) . "</Q>".PHP_EOL;
            $xml .= "</L>".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    return $xml;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will do the trick.

```
function get_order_item_lines($skus = '', $qty = '')
{
    $xml = '';

    if (!empty($skus) && is_array($skus))
    {
        foreach ($skus as $key => $sku)
        {
            $skuUpper = strtoupper($sku); // change to upper
            
            if ($skuUpper != 'WANHAO-STICKER'
                && strpos($skuUpper, 'NWS-', 0) === false)  // string not contains..
            {
                $xml .= "<L>".PHP_EOL;
                $xml .= "<P>" . $sku . "</P>".PHP_EOL;
                $xml .= "<Q>" . (empty($qty[$key]) ? "" : $qty[$key]) . "</Q>".PHP_EOL;
                $xml .= "</L>".PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $skus = explode( ",", $skus );

        if ( !empty( $skus[0] ) && !empty( $qty[0] ) ) 
        {
            $skuUpper = strtoupper($skus[0]); // change to upper
            
            if ($skuUpper != 'WANHAO-STICKER'
                && strpos($skuUpper, 'NWS-', 0) === false)
            {
                $xml .= "<L>".PHP_EOL;
                $xml .= "<P>" . trim( $skus[0] ) . "</P>".PHP_EOL;
                $xml .= "<Q>" . (empty($qty[0]) ? "" : $qty[0]) . "</Q>".PHP_EOL;
                $xml .= "</L>".PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

    return $xml;
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, You always save my day!

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to the **return**  , do not return (leave the function) when you mean to **continue** the foreach iteration.  Your code is erroneous in doing this:

```
foreach ($skus as $key => $sku){
    $sku = strtoupper($sku);
    if ($sku == "X" || $sku == "Y" || $sku == "Z") return "";
```

The above return "";  leaves the function entirely when it finds a $sku being X, Y, or Z and returns NOTHING. Your question/problem states you get an EMPTY value, that's exactly why. If it finds 1 sku with either X, Y, or Z it's going to RETURN.  If all you want to do is continue , then let it continue while skipping X, Y, Z skus.

```
foreach ($skus as $key => $sku){
  $sku = strtoupper($sku);
  if ( $sku == "X" || $sku == "Y" || $sku == "Z") {
    //ignore these skus and continue foreach
    continue;
  }

  $good_skus[] = $sku;
}

var_dump($good_skus);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added strtoupper in both if and else statement, but still empty output. I have added the complete function in the initial post.

Comment: The reason it's returning no value it you're having it return.  Replace return with continue

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried to add your code, but I get a fatal error. I have updated the initial post. I am sorry, I am not that skilled..

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, if the array is more complex you could use `array_filter()` and use `in_array()` with an array of the SKU's to remove...

```
$filteredSkus = array_filter($skus, function ($sku) use ($skusToRemove){
    return !in_array($sku, $skusToRemove);
});
```

Or if the SKU is simply the value in the array, you can `array_diff()` with an array of the SKU's to remove...

```
$difSkus = array_diff($skus, $skusToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to Nigel Ren's answer which is correct in my opinion, here an example to your question:

```
// remove skus X, Y, and Z
$filteredSkus = array_filter($skus, static function($sku) {
    return !($sku === 'X' || $sku === 'Y' || $sku === 'Z')
});
```

If you want to filter skus which start with these letters you need to use strpos like that:

```
// remove skus starting with X, Y, and Z
$filteredSkus = array_filter($skus, static function($sku) {
    return !(
        strpos(strtoupper($sku, 'X')) === 0 ||
        strpos(strtoupper($sku, 'Y')) === 0 ||
        strpos(strtoupper($sku, 'Z')) === 0
    )
});
```